# Run python package globally from terminal

Tags: python, bash, terminal, cmder

I have a python package i developed to be a CLI which parses user location as params and returns the temperature for that specific location like so:

```sh
python weather.py --lat=[my_latitude] --long=[my_longitude]
```

I would like this command to be accessible globally, and not only when i'm in current project folder. In `weather.py` i set the first line to `#!path_to_python`, and i already made file permissions to read and execute, and then tried moving the file to a folder that is in my PATH. When i run `weather` in terminal, it outputs nothing.

I'm using Windows 10 with cmder terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you package your program correctly using Setuptools, you can [have it create a console script launcher](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) for your program automatically (just like e.g. `pip` does!).

Those scripts are installed into your Python installation's Scripts directory on Windows, which is generally automatically on your PATH.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look. I had no idea it could manage it automatically.